# How can I install pip for python 3.3

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, python, python3

I have installed python 2.7 and python 3.3 on server and now I need to install **pip** for **python 3.3**.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

This will install pip for python 3.2 (I haven't installed python 3.2)

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

This will install pip for python 3.2

I need to install some packages with python 3.3 (lxml, ftplib, etc...) and for that I need pip.

I cannot setup only python 3.3 because I also need python 2.7 (for odoo).

Can anyone guide me in proper direction.

Comment: Try adding `python3.3` to `PATH`as explained in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183112/installing-pip-for-pyth).

Comment: I already refer this, can please elaborate more what I need to add it to the PATH ?

Answer (score 0):

> » I need to install some packages with python 3.3 (lxml, ftplib,
>   etc...) and for that I need pip «

Then please do `dpkg -L python3-pip` to know that the python3-pip is `/usr/bin/pip3`

Installing with pip3 : `pip3 install [package]`